# Show larger model Swift SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

How do I do "zoom" in to the models face? The effect I want to achieve is so that the model's face takes up about the whole circle. 
[Link to pic](https://gyazo.com/6af34cef9756b9746705ee020e8c0236)

I have tried changing **Z** value of `cameraNode.position` to less than *2*, but then the model clips. I've also tried changing `cameraNode.camera.zNear` & `cameraNode.camera.zFar` but then nothing shows. `cameraNode.camera.xFov` and `cameraNode.camera.yFov` both are *0.0* if I don't change them.

```
    // Get the model height
    var minPoint = SCNVector3Zero
    var maxPoint = SCNVector3Zero
    modelNode.getBoundingBoxMin(&minPoint, max: &maxPoint)
    let modelHeight = maxPoint.y - minPoint.y

    // Remove old camera
    self.cameraNode.removeFromParentNode()
    cameraNode = SCNNode()

    // Set up a new camera
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0, modelHeight, 2)

    // Set up LookAtConstraint
    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: SCNNode())
    constraint.target.position = SCNVector3(0, modelHeight, 0)
    cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]

    self.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
```

Answer (score 2):

Breakdown on camera usage:

---

`Camera.position`:

This adjusts a camera's position (obviously).

This is just like moving a camera around in the "Real-World".

---

`Camera.zNear`:

This controls when the object will be clipped.

Why?

In the real world, if you try moving your camera through the wall.. It won't work!

However in `SceneKit` you can do this, but if you try to move the camera through the wall what should happen?

Should the camera break?

Should the wall break and the camera go through?

Should the wall be invisible when it becomes to close to the camera?

The third choice is what SceneKit uses.

`zNear` tells the camera how close the object needs to be in order to become invisible.

---

`Camera.zFar`:

This is to optimize SceneKit.

If you have a large scene and the camera can see everything, even when it's far away (it's real tiny though) it uses up extra memory.

This tells the camera how far it can see.

---

`Camera.xFov`/`Camera.yFov`:

These are a bit more tricky to understand.

These are used to control how large of an angle you can see, for example,
the human eyes can see about 180 degrees whereas your default camera can see about 60 degrees.

here is an example:(the camera's position does not move)

This would be a small angle on xyFov:
[image: small xyFov]

This would be a more "normal" angle on xyFov:
[image: normal xyFov]
As you can see now you can see some of the room around the camera with a greater xyFov.

And with an insanely large xyFov:
[image: large xyFov]
Even though you may see it in a static image, this camera can see something beside it, clearly. It may not look so bad, but if you animate anything, it looks super "fish-eye".

---

### Now, Based on this knowledge:

You might get what your looking for if you leave the camera in a position where it doesn't clip your scene, then set your xyFov to something like 20, and play around with that number till it's right.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please note as of 2018 these APIs have changed watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am a little bit confused about what your code shall do. But sometimes it helps to think into a different direction. I mostly use something like this:

```
    //MARK: Init
override init() {
    super.init()
    self.makeCameraFocusNode()
    self.makeCamera()
}

//MARK: Setup
func makeCameraFocusNode() {
    self.cameraHeight = 0
    self.cameraFocusNode = SCNNode.init()
    self.cameraFocusNode?.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    self.addChildNode(self.cameraFocusNode!)
}

/* Default Setup for camera. */
func makeCamera() {
    self.pointOfView = SCNNode.init()
    self.pointOfView?.camera = SCNCamera.init()
    self.pointOfView?.position = SCNVector3Make(13, 16, 13)

    let constrain : SCNLookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint.init(target: self.cameraFocusNode)
    constrain.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
    self.pointOfView?.constraints = [constrain]
    self.cameraFocusNode?.addChildNode(self.pointOfView!)
}
```

There I setup a node what the camera has to focus. When you add the camera to that focus node, you can move the camera by making a SCNAction on the focus node. It is as simple as this:

```
    func moveUp(toHeight: Float) {
    let position = SCNVector3Make((self.cameraFocusNode?.position.x)!,
                                  toHeight,
                                  (self.cameraFocusNode?.position.z)!)
    self.cameraFocusNode?.runAction(SCNAction.move(to: position, duration: 0.3))
}
```

In this example the camera only changes in height whenever you give a new height into that method. But for now I have not figured out how to use Actions on the camera itself. This would be easier for complex camera movements. But just moving the focus node might hel for zooming.